# I want to add the result which I am getting in div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I want to do is to get the data from the table, add them and display them.

I have the following table.

[image: Table]

I am giving input in a textbox and getting the result in div. I am using append to display the result. Now after displaying the result I want to just add the price and display it.

The output

[image: Output]

My main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <p align="center" style="font-size:20px" > Scan the Barcode of the    Product  </p>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" id="item" style="text-align:centre" placeholder=" Barcode ID" autofocus /> <!--text box -->

        <div id="item-data"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> <!--jquery link-->
        <script src="js/global.js"></script> <!--linking event file-->

</body>
</html>
```

My javascript file

```
$(function(){


//press enter on text area..

$('#item').keypress(function (event) {
var key = event.which;
if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
{

var item = $('input#item').val();    // retreiving the value from the item
    if ($.trim(item) != ''){            //send this to php file but if its   empty or spaces(trim) are there dont send it//
        $.post('ajax/name.php',{id:item}, function(data){   //using post  method sending to the father(name.php), sending the data through the file item
            $('div#item-data').append(""+data+"</br>"); // grabing the data and displaying it

});

}

$('#item').val('');
}
});

});
```

The name.php file

```
<?php

require '../db/connect.php';

$id= $_POST['id']; // your post variable
$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"];
    }
}
else
{
        echo "ID not found, Please Scan again";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: check out my answer `$sum` will have the final summed up price.

Comment: let me know if it solves ur query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $sum = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"];
        $sum = floatval($sum) + floatval($row["price"]);

       // or $sum = $sum + (int)($row["price"]);
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: I tried this it seems in the existing output I am getting the price twice price : 3030.

Comment: @hammadrashid try my updated answer. Add `floatval` to `$row['price']`

Comment: @hammadrashid what is price datatype in database? Its actually considering it as string val

Comment: for price its int(11)

Comment: @hammadrashid try this `(int)` instead of floatval

Comment: Its giving Fatal error: Call to undefined function int()

Comment: @hammadrashid try this `$sum = floatval($sum) + floatval($row["price"]);` update my answer as well. This has to work out.

Comment: Not even this its showing the same thing 1 shirt color: Blue price: 3030
2 shirt color: green price: 3535.

Comment: @hammadrashid give me some time will work on this. You have placed the echo outside the loop rignt?

Comment: Yeah sure take your time. Yeap it is outside the loop.

Comment: @hammadrashid I actually need to have some sleep its 3am here in India.

Comment: Well its 1:30am in dubai. Just let me know if you are able to solve it, it will be great help.

Comment: @hammadrashid Yes sure. In meanwhile just try out yourself its actually combining values because its treating it as strings and not int or decimals.

Comment: Yeah I will check as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add to a variable in that loop you've got... Then append that.

```
$total += $row['price']

...

echo $total
```

Of you could execute another SQL statement to get it. But I don't see the point of that.

Comment: I added it in the while loop and echoed it in the end, but I am getting parse error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\ajax\name.php on line 15. Line 15 is echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. " price: " . $row["price"];.